# Cygwin - tail stops reading input pipe after first write

Tags: pipe, cygwin, tail, stdin

I have the following script to run my application in Ubuntu with redirecting its input (where $in is named pipe which is used to send text lines to stdin).

```
tail -f "$in" | "$app_bin" $app_args &
```

I can send input to my application when needed with:

```
printf "%s\n" "text input" >> "$in"
```

However, when running in Cygwin environment (Windows), the second command works only the first time! Then you try to send second line of text, it freezes without any action, while trying to manipulate $in gives error "Device or resource busy".

How did you solve this problem? Is it Cygwin specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a incomplete implementation

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-01/msg00085.html